# Using QtMobility in QtCreator: Setup?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qt-creator, qt-mobility

I am trying to set up a development environment to play around with developing Qt apps for Symbian devices.  I have succesfully set up the environment and am able to create simple apps such as HelloWorld and get them to run on my device.  I would now like to try using the QtMobility package, but I am struggling to get it to work in QtCreator.

I got some sample code for using the camera (initially I only had QtMobility 1.0.2, but I have now downloaded the 1.1.0 technology preview version).  I followed the instructions in the help file to install it, here is what I did:

```
Extracted the zip file to C:\QtMobility
Opened a Qt Command prompt and ran configure (in the QtMobility directory)
Ran mingw32-make
Ran mingw32-make install
Finally I updated my PATH variable to include C:\QtMobility\lib
```

I went back to QtCreator (restarted it) and looked at the cpp file that first calls the macro `QTM_USE_NAMESPACE` but it is still underlined in red, because it can't find the `qmobilityglobal.h` file.

Does anyone know if I have missed anything out during the installation that will tell the QtCreator where to find the QtMobility header files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mingw32-make` suggests you're building for `win32-mingw` target environment. To work with Symbian SDKs, you should be building for e.g. `symbian-abld` instead. The `configure.bat` script will auto-detect the target you are building for. Just make sure that `QT_PATH` environment variable points to a location where you have a Symbian build of the Qt toolchain.

(Also note that `make install` is unnecessary with `symbian-abld` - the build step already puts everything in place in Symbian SDK directories.)

Comment: So if all I want to do is compile apps that use the new features in QtMobility 1.1.0 and install them on a device, then I should just run `configure`, then `symbian-abld` and Qt Creator will pick up on the new header files?

Comment: `configure` followed by `make`, provided that your Qt configuration is ok (`QT_PATH` environment variable)